# Can every undirected graph be transformed into an equivalent graph (for the purposes of path-finding) with a maximum degree of 3 in logspace?

Tags: graphs, space-complexity

Can every undirected graph be transformed into an equivalent graph (for the purposes of path-finding) with a maximum degree of 3 in logspace?

Given an undirected graph `G`, is there another graph, `H`, such that:

- all vertices of `G` are in `H`
- H is allowed extra vertices not in G
- if `a` and `b` are connected in `G`, `a` and `b` are also connected in in `H` (possibly with at least some of the extra vertices in the `H` path from `a` to `b`)
- if `c` and `d` are not connected in `G`, `c` and `d` are not connected in `H`
- each vertex in `H` has degree at most 3
- the edges of `H` can be enumerated in logspace given an input `G`

Maybe this could be called a logspace reduction of G to a graph that has max degree of 3 that preserves connectivity?

Answer (score 5):

For each edge $(u,v)$ in $G$, add vertices $w_{u,v}$ and $w_{v,u}$ to $H$, and add the edge $(w_{u,v},w_{v,u})$ to $H$.

For each vertex $u$ in $G$, if $u$ has edges $(u,v_1),\dots,(u,v_k)$, then add edges $(w_{u,v_i},w_{u,v_{i+1}})$ and $(u,w_{u,v_1})$ to $H$; and add edges $(w_{v_i,u},w_{v_{i+1},u})$ and $(w_{v_1,u},v)$ to $H$.

I believe this $H$ satisfies all of your properties.  Also, I believe it can be constructed in logspace (please check me and verify for yourself).